# Is there any other way to implement this code so that zip function is also used?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So there's this problem. I've been able to get to the output. The output is perfect. But there's this assignment which demands that along with split() and map() function, zip() should also be used. I don't know how I can change the code so that I can use zip() as well.

Input should take two strings:

`["1 5 3","2 6 -1"]`

Output should display the multiplication of each position of the two strings as a list in integer form:

`[2, 30, -3]`

This is my code:

```
def transform():
    L="1 5 3"
    L1="2 6 -1"
    x=L.split()
    x1=L1.split()
    y=list(map(int,x))
    n=len(y)
    y2=list(map(int,x1))
    F=[y[i]*y2[i] for i in range (0,n)]
    return F
```

Output is perfect. But any idea how zip function can be used as well?

Comment: simply change last line to: `F = [e[0] * e[1] for e in zip(y, y2)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
def transform():
     L="1 5 3"
     L1="2 6 -1"
     x=L.split()
     x1=L1.split()
     y=list(map(int,x))
     n=len(y)
     y2=list(map(int,x1))
     F = zip(y,y2)
     return [i[0]*i[1] for i in F]
print(transform())
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `zip()`, `map()` and `str.split()`:

```
lst = ["1 5 3","2 6 -1"]

print(list(map(lambda x: int(x[0]) * int(x[1]), zip(*map(str.split, lst)))))
```

Prints:

```
[2, 30, -3]
```

NOTE: I would recommend using list comprehensions/for-loops for readability.

Comment: What if the function should take two arguments? As in two separate strings. Works perfectly by the way!

Comment: @TheVaibhavJ You could use `list(map(lambda x: int(x[0]) * int(x[1]), zip(*map(str.split, [s1, s2]))))` where `s1` and `s2` are two strings, for example `"1 5 3", "2 6 -1"`

Answer (score 2):

Using list-comprehension, you can do:

```
[int(x) * int(y) for x, y in zip(lst[0].split(), lst[1].split())]
```

**Example**:

```
lst = ["1 5 3","2 6 -1"]

print([int(x) * int(y) for x, y in zip(lst[0].split(), lst[1].split())])
# [2, 30, -3]
```

Comment: Fastest solution posted here (tested with timeit).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple solution.

```py
l = ["1 5 3","2 6 -1"]
a = [int(i)*int(j) for i,j in zip(*[i.split() for i in l])]
```

Outputs:

```
[2, 30, -3]
```

Similar to what some other folks suggested.

---

Some speed comparison (Austin's is the fastest implementation.)

```py
import timeit

def austin():
    l = ["1 5 3","2 6 -1"]
    return [int(x) * int(y) for x, y in zip(l[0].split(), l[1].split())]

def felipe():
    l = ["1 5 3","2 6 -1"]
    return [int(i)*int(j) for i,j in zip(*[i.split() for i in l])]

def andrej():
    l = ["1 5 3","2 6 -1"]
    return list(map(lambda x: int(x[0]) * int(x[1]), zip(*map(str.split, l))))

print("Austin", timeit.timeit(austin))
print("Felipe", timeit.timeit(felipe))
print("Andrej", timeit.timeit(andrej))
```

Outputs on my computer:

```
Austin 2.398316105
Felipe 2.9961890580000006
Andrej 3.4555498620000007
```

Comment: `" "` is the default of `split()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without `map`, just using `string's split` and `zip`

```
>>> l = ["1 5 3","2 6 -1"]
>>> int_l = [[int(e) for e in sl.split()] for sl in l]
>>> int_l
[[1, 5, 3], [2, 6, -1]]
>>> 
>>> [x*y for x, y in zip(*int_l)]
[2, 30, -3]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` with three arguments instead of `zip`

```
from operator import mul

def transform(L, L1):
    L_ints  = map(int, L.split())
    L1_ints = map(int, L1.split())
    return list(map(mul, L_ints, L1_ints))

print(transform("1 5 3", "2 6 -1"))
# [2, 30, -3]
```